# Is the winding order of exploded region segments consistent in bricscad?

Tags: autocad, bricscad

I have tried exploding a few regions in bricscad and it would seem like the curves defining the positive part are always wound counter-clockwise, while the negative ones wind clockwise. However I cannot find any confirmation in the documentation that this will always be the case.

An exploded region, it's curves are colour coded along the HSV circle according to their index in the resulting DbObjectCollection:

[image]

Comment: Please excuse my ignorance, but is this a programming question?

Comment: Maybe not strictly. I encountered this while writing a bricscad plugin, but you are right that the question by itself is about how the cad works in general and no longer about the plugin. Didn't realise that, sorry ':-)

Comment: I would say this isn’t guaranteed behavior and that it’s a side effect of the implementation.
Though it should be consistent at least through a version. I’m sure there’s algorithms to check this over at theswamp.org
Why do you want to know, are you trying to join them?

Comment: I needed to work with the curves that make up the region in my algorithm, and it is important to me whether a given curve is a part of the "inner" or "outer" boundary of the region. I know there are gonna be other ways to do this (for example, joining each connected loop together and then measuring the bounds size, biggest should be the positive and all other subtracted), but I got curious about the winding, so I asked :-D.

Comment: By the way, I have been playing with the Editor.TraceBoundary() command and it spits out one or multiple polylines, that seem to follow the same winding order depending on whether they are positive or negative. Kind of lends credibility to it being consistent, but if there's no official statement/documentation saying so I probably wouldn't rely on it.